# Is there a good replacement for onloadend in html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was wondering if anyone knows a good supplement for `GlobalEventHandlers.onloadend`. It functions perfectly for my purposes, but is **only** supported by Firefox so I would like a more universal approach.

Specifically, I have a load event handler like so:

```
image.addEventListener('load', function(){
   ctxA.canvas.width = image.width;
   ctxA.canvas.height = image.height;
   ctxA.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

   let imageData = ctxA.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
   filterData(imageData, image.height, image.width);
});
```

My filterData function takes a while to execute. It's not forever, but it's noticeable. I would like to draw the image to the page first, and then use the data. However, the browser does not seem to draw the image until the load event handler is fully complete.
I confirmed this by purposely making an infinite while loop in the load event handler and the image is never printed.

This makes sense as an image probably shouldn't be drawn until all load requirements are met. However, I do not know of a good way to display the image and then execute the filterData function other than onloadend. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: (I like *replacement* better than *supplement*.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What blocks your page is not the loading of your image but your js code.
Blocking the JS execution will also block the event-loop, which is responsible of updating the rendering. So by extension, blocking the JS execution also means blocking the rendering.

And this is bad.

So you don't need an other event, which by the way looked like it was working only because by chance, you were blocking the rendering *after* the browser had time to render once, even though it wasn't a given that at this time it would have rendered, and nor do you want to wait for a random amount of time, which you can't be sure will be enough either (rendering happens 60 times per seconds with a 60Hz monitor, the event loop spins far faster, so anything below 17ms on such a device may fire before).

So what's the best in your case?

**Move your computation to a Dedicated Worker.**
Workers run in a parallel thread and don't block the UI thread, meaning the browser can continue to update the rendering, and take your users' input etc. while your heavy computation is still being made.

To start a Worker you need a second script which will listen to a "message" event from the main page, where you'll transfer the ImageData you got from your canvas through the Worker's `postMessage` method.
Once the computation is done, you'll be able to transfer the resulting ImageData back to the main thread to do whatever you want with it.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( "canvas" );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
const worker = new Worker( getWorkerURL() );

const img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";
img.onload = (evt) => {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
  const imgData = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  // transfer the ImageData to the worker
  worker.postMessage( imgData, [ imgData.data.buffer ] );
};

worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
  // draw back on the canvas
  ctx.putImageData( data, 0, 0 );
};


function getWorkerURL() {
  const script = `
  onmessage = ({ data }) => {
    const { width, height } = data;
    const arr = data.data;
    // a stoopid filter
    for( let y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
      for( let x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
        const index = ((y * width) + x) * 4;
        const r = arr[ index ];
        const g = arr[ index + 1 ];
        const b = arr[ index + 2 ];
        arr[ index ] = g ^ b;
        arr[ index + 1 ] = r ^ g
        arr[ index + 2 ] = b ^ r;
      }
    }
    // make it last longer
    const now = performance.now();
    while( performance.now() - now < 2500 ) {
    
    }
    postMessage( data );
  }
 `;
 const blob = new Blob( [ script ], { type: "text/javascript" } );
 return URL.createObjectURL( blob );

}
```

```css
canvas { background: white }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

---

If you can't move the computation to a Worker (but here I'm rather confident that you can), to correctly wait that the browser has rendered before blocking the UI, wait the next event-loop iteration **after** an animation-frame.

```
const performAfterRendering = (task) => {
  requestAnimationFrame( () => setTimeout( task, 0 ) );
};
```

Comment: Although Barmar's solution worked for my purposes, this solution does a far better job of explaining why I was having the problem and will prevent me from blocking the event loop in the future. Very well written and will speed up my code.

Answer (score -1):

Call `filterData()` asynchronously so you don't wait for it while seeing the rendered image.

```
image.addEventListener('load', function(){
   ctxA.canvas.width = image.width;
   ctxA.canvas.height = image.height;
   ctxA.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

   let imageData = ctxA.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
   setTimeout(() => filterData(imageData, image.height, image.width), 0);
});
```